# Is 'yield self' the same as instance_eval?

Tags: ruby

**Is there any difference if you define Foo with instance_eval: . . .**

```
class Foo
    def initialize(&block)
      instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
    end
  end
```

**. . . or with 'yield self':**

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
```

In either case you can do this:

```
x = Foo.new { def foo; 'foo'; end }
x.foo
```

So '`yield self`' means that the block after Foo.new is always evaluated in the context of the Foo class.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your two pieces of code do very different things. By using instance_eval you're evaluating the block in the context of your object. This means that using def will define methods on that object. It also means that calling a method without a receiver inside the block will call it on your object.

When yielding self you're passing self as an argument to the block, but since your block doesn't take any arguments, it is simply ignored. So in this case yielding self does the same thing as yielding nothing. The `def` here behaves exactly like a `def` outside the block would, yielding self does not actually change what you define the method on. What you could do is:

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end
x = Foo.new {|obj| def obj.foo() 'foo' end}
x.foo
```

The difference to instance_eval being that you have to specify the receiver explicitly.

Edit to clarify:

In the version with yield, obj in the block will be the object that is yielded, which in this case is is the newly created Foo instance. While self will have the same value it had outside the block. With the instance_eval version `self` inside the block will be the newly created Foo instance.

Comment: In your "Edit to clarify", don't you mean that self is yielded to the obj in the block? Maybe I'm just reading it a different way but I see the object being initialized, self is yielded to the block as 'obj' and then inside the block the method foo is defined on self through obj.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, we mean the same thing. I wrote "the newly created Foo instance" because self inside the initialize method (which is the newly created Foo instance) is not the same as self inside the block and if you just say "self", it's unclear which one you mean.

Answer (score 8):

They are different. `yield(self)` does not change the value of `self` inside the block, while `instance_eval(&block)` does.

```
class Foo
  def with_yield
    yield(self)
  end

  def with_instance_eval(&block)
    instance_eval(&block)
  end
end

f = Foo.new

f.with_yield do |arg|
  p self
  # => main
  p arg
  # => #<Foo:0x100124b10>
end

f.with_instance_eval do |arg|
  p self
  # => #<Foo:0x100124b10>
  p arg
  # => #<Foo:0x100124b10>
end
```

Comment: The second `p arg` should print `nil`, not `#<Foo:0x100124b10>`.

Comment: In 1.8.7, the Foo instance is printed. I thought it would be nil as well, not sure why it isn't.

Comment: In 1.9 nil is printed. I can't see any explanation for 1.8.7 printing the Foo instance. Are you sure you didn't misread the output?

Comment: 1.8.7 prints the Foo instance because self is passed as an undocumented argument to instance_eval in 1.8.7. This undocumented argument was removed in revision 9937 (http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/ruby_1_8_7/eval.c?r1=9936&r2=9937&diff_format=h) and re-added in revision 10063 (http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/branches/ruby_1_8_7/eval.c?r1=10047&r2=10063&diff_format=h) making it into the tree in time for 1.8.7 (http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/tags/v1_8_7/eval.c?annotate=16730&diff_format=h)

Comment: Quick update, in 1.9.2 and 1.9.3 the Foo instance is printed.

Answer (score 6):

You just can drop the **self** keyword

```
class Foo
  def initialize
    yield if block_given?
  end
end
```

**Update from comments**

Using **yield** there is a bit new to my taste, specially when used outside irb.

However there is a big and significant difference between **instance_eval** approach and **yield** approach, check this snippet:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(&block)
    instance_eval(&block) if block_given?
  end
end
x = Foo.new { def foo; 'foo'; end }            
#=> #<Foo:0xb800f6a0>                                            
x.foo #=> "foo"                                                        
z = Foo.new  #=> #<Foo:0xb800806c>                                            
z.foo #=>NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #<Foo:0xb800806c>
```

Check this one as well:

```
class Foo2
  def initialize
    yield if block_given?
  end
end
x = Foo2.new { def foo; 'foo'; end } #=> #<Foo:0xb7ff1bb4>
x.foo #=> private method `foo' called for #<Foo2:0xb8004930> (NoMethodError)
x.send :foo => "foo"
z = Foo.new  #=> #<Foo:0xb800806c> 
z.send :foo => "foo"
```

As you can see the difference is that the former one is adding a singleton method **foo** to the object being initialized, while the later is adding a private method to all instances of Object class.

Comment: "As you can see the difference is that the former one is adding a singleton method foo to the object being initialized, while the later is adding that method to all instances of class Foo2" Actually, the latter is adding the method to Object (and in real ruby (as opposed to irb) it will add it as a private method so you can't do x.foo or z.foo, just foo). In other words the def behaves exactly as if you had written it outside the block (unless the method does not yield of course, in which case nothing happens).

Comment: In Ruby 1.9, you do not get the private method definition. Instead,

x = Foo2.new { def foo; 'foo'; end }

will define the method 'foo' on Object (as sepp2k said). You can see this by saying:

x.methods(false).grep /foo/
# => []

Object.new.foo
# => "foo"